# How to save the values of a prime factorization in the array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, prime-factoring

My issue right now is that I need to do a prime factorization with a given number. Then I need to store the values (the dividers and the power) into a 2d array. `x[0][] = the dividers and x[1][] the powers.`

So f.ex. if the number is 8 then the divider is 2 and the power is 3 because 2^3=8

This is my code:

My first step is to check if the array is empty in case of the number 1

```
public static long[][] primfactorization(long givenNumber) {

    if (givenNumber == 1) {
        long [][] empty = {{},{}};
        return empty;
    }
```

Then the second step is to declare some variables and also create the 2d array that I later on have to return (also I use sqrt and not Math.sqrt since it's forbidden to use classes/methods of the java api here). Issue here is that I know the first bracket has to have the size 2 because it only has 2 rows (divider and power) but I don't know yet what I should enter in the second bracket as I don't know how many divider each number will have.

```
int index = 0;
int count = 0;
int i=2;
long z = (long) sqrt(n);
long[][] a = new long[2][ (int) z];
```

Then I start with the "real" prime factorization and it works perfectly fine. The main problem here is that I cannot save the dividers and powers into the array. Like I tried it by using a new variable called index (declared at the start of my method) but then it can save the same divider multiple times f.ex. `x[0][1] = 2 and x[0][2] = 2` and I only need it once. Also the power is not working as intended just yet as it starts with 1 and just goes up by 1 every time the loop is done but it is supposed to go up by the amount of the same divider that appears (f.ex. the divider 2 appears 3 times then the power should be 3).Thanks in advance.

```
while(givenNumber%2==0) {
givenNumber=givenNumber/2;
count++; //power   8 = 2.2.2 => count = 3
}
i++;
for (i = 3; i <= z; i = i+2) {
// While i divides l, print i and divide l
while (givenNumber%i == 0) {
    int temp = i;
 //ToDo: save the divider in array[0][]
    count++; //ToDo: save the power in array[1][]
    givenNumber = givenNumber/i;
    i = temp;
    a[0][index] = temp;
    a[1][index] = count;
    index++;
  }
}
return a;
}
```

Comment: Don't increment `index` _inside_ the inner loop; do it **after** the inner loop, right at the end of the _outer_ loop where you're about to move onto the next divisor.

Comment: Must you use an array for this?  A map would be better.  You can always convert the map to an array for the final result.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 2; i <= z; i = i+2) {
    count = 0;
    while (n%i == 0) {
        count++;
        n = n/i;
    }
    if (count > 0) {
        x[0][index] = i;
        x[1][index] = count;
        index++;
    }
    if (i == 2)
        --i;
}
return x;
```

I have made some changes the 'actual factorization' part:

1. `count` has to be set to zero for each new value of the divisor i
2. I have moved the assignment of the the array `x` outside the while loop. Ideally it should be done only after the 'power' has been counted. It is done only when `count > 0`.
3. Removed `temp`. It was unnecessary.
4. I had noticed that for the divisor you only checked odd numbers and additionally checked 2 at the start. However, array `x` wasn't updated accordingly for 2. I have removed the while loop, and the factor-checking for 2, is now done along with the other numbers, inside the for loop. I added an if statement for the special case of 2, to achieve the same result you had intended for.

> I don't know yet what I should enter in the second bracket as I don't know how many divider each number will have.

It is impractical to calculate the size requirements beforehand. Since the java API cannot be used, it would be simplest create a function which would effectively change the size of your array. **This achieves the resizability of a list, while using only arrays**.

```
/**
@return the reference to be assigned to x
@param - arr: The array x
@param - newSize: The array size can be increased or decreased to newSize
*/
static long[][] resize(long[][] arr, int newSize) {
    long[][] temp = new long[2][newSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr[0].length && i < newSize; ++i) {
        temp[0][i] = arr[0][i];
        temp[1][i] = arr[1][i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Using this function:

1. When the array `x` is full, its size can be increase by an arbitrary number.
2. When the execution is complete `x` can be trimmed down to the correct size.

**Here is proper working program which shows everything in action.** Try running it.

```
import java.util.Arrays; // I am aware that imports are not allowed, but have used this class only for display of output
import java.util.Scanner;
class Factorizer {
    public static long[][] primfactorization(long n) {
        int index = 0;
        int count = 0;
        long z = (long) Math.sqrt(n);
        long[][] x = new long[2][5];
        for (int i = 2; i <= z; i = i+2) {
            count = 0;
            while (n%i == 0) {
                count++;
                n = n/i;
            }
            if (count > 0) {
                x[0][index] = i;
                x[1][index] = count;
                index++;
            }
            if (index >= x[0].length) // resizing array when it is too small
                x = resize(x, index + 5); // 5 being an arbitrary number
            if (i == 2)
                --i;
        }
        return resize(x, index); //trimming down the size before returning
    }
    static long[][] resize(long[][] arr, int newSize) {
        long[][] temp = new long[2][newSize];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr[0].length && i < newSize; ++i) {
            temp[0][i] = arr[0][i];
            temp[1][i] = arr[1][i];
        }
        return temp;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        long n = new Scanner(System.in).nextLong();
        System.out.println (Arrays.deepToString(primfactorization(n)));
    }
}
```

Final Note:

1. The special checking done, in case 1 is the parameter, is unnecessary. I have removed it.
2. There is a special case where this program does not work perfectly correctly. If a prime number is given as parameter, it is not included as a factor. This is because the `for-loop` runs only till `sqrt(n)`. This can be rectified by setting the for-loop's upper limit to `n`, or through another `if` condition in the body of the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that help it's just that I need to use an array and cannot do it with a list but the rest really helped me a lot

Comment: @EgZoShift I would like to clarify that the code in my answer does use only arrays. It creates a new array with a different size, copies the elements from the old array and assigns the new array to `x`. I have edited my answer, so please go through the latter half.

Comment: Yo thanks for still helping but I forgot to tell you I alrdy fixed my mistake and now it is working perfectly fine. But got a new method with an error now so working on that 1 xD but as I said rly glad for ur help the entire time. Wish you a nice evening

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `Map` for this. The key can be the actual factor and the value and be the count.  This eliminates the possibility of the containing array either exceeding its length or having to over allocate space to hold potential factors.

```
int[] test = { 25, 282, 301, 292922, Integer.MAX_VALUE };
for (int n : test) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> factors = findFactors(n);
    System.out.println(n + " -> " + factors);
}
```

Prints

```
25 -> {5=2}
282 -> {2=1, 3=1, 47=1}
301 -> {7=1, 43=1}
292922 -> {2=1, 7=4, 61=1}
2147483647 -> {2147483647=1}
```

If required, you can convert the map to an array either before returning the factors from the method or just before you print them.  Here is an example of the latter.

```
for (int n : test) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> factors = findFactors(n);
    int[][] results = factors.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> new int[] { e.getKey(), e.getValue() })
            .toArray(int[][]::new);
    System.out.println(n + " -> " + Arrays.deepToString(results));  
}
```

Prints

```
25 -> [[5, 2]]
282 -> [[2, 1], [3, 1], [47, 1]]
301 -> [[7, 1], [43, 1]]
292922 -> [[2, 1], [7, 4], [61, 1]]
2147483647 -> [[2147483647, 1]]
```

And here is the method that returns a Map.  Note that `BigInteger` is used to check and see if the current updated value is a prime.  This is critical to achieve optimum performance.  For example, when a very large number is the product of relatively small primes and then a very large prime. To see the difference, try `Integer.MAX_VALUE` with and without that check.

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> findFactors(int val) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> factors = new HashMap<>();

    // the initial prime
    int prime = 2;
    int c = 1;
    
    while (val > 1) {

        // update divisions and add to the map.
        int count = 0;
        while (val % prime == 0) {
            count++;
            val /= prime;
        }
        if (count > 0) {
            factors.put(prime, count);
        }
        
        // now do a check to see if the current value is a prime.
        if (BigInteger.valueOf(val).isProbablePrime(99)) {
            factors.put(val, 1);
            break;
        }
        // compute next factor.
        prime = (c++ * 2 + 1);
        
    }
    return factors;
}
```

Note: `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is a [Mercenne Prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20Mersenne%20prime,in%20the%20early%2017th%20century) which has the form of 2<sup>n</sup>-1 where `n` is a prime.  In this case, `n = 31`.